# Finer and Coarse Topology on Space of Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $C[0,1]$ to be the set of continuous functions from the closed interval to $\mathbb{R}$.  The following describe a metric space over $\mathbb{R}$.

$$\rho(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(t)-g(t)|\; dt \mbox{ and } \rho '(f,g)= \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$$

We must show that the topology $\mathcal{T}_\rho$ is a subset $\mathcal{T}_{\rho '}$ and that the reverse containment does NOT hold.

$\textbf{Attempt:}$

I understand that to show this I need to find $B_{\rho'}(f,\varepsilon ') \subset B_\rho(f,\varepsilon )$ as this would show the containment.

I attempted to break apart these two open balls in their respective topologies per their description and I have an intuitive feel but and am not sure how to show the proper containment.

$$\int_{0}^{1} | f(t) - g(t) | \; dt = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Bigg|f\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) - g\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) \Bigg|$$

As $0<1/n <1$ as $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that the supremum on the interval can be found via:
$$\Bigg|f\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) - g\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) \Bigg| < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Bigg|f\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) - g\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) \Bigg| \mbox{ for some }k $$.

As both $f$ and $g$ are continuous we have the existence of such a $k$ and moreover $k/n$.

Any advice on how to fix this or proceed correctly would be helpful!

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Bigg|f\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) - g\Big(\frac{k}{n} \Big) \Bigg| \leq \rho' (f,g)$?

Comment: Am I not supposed to show the reverse relation? Or is this saying that because the relation you have mentioned is true thus the above always holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the Mean value theorem for integral which states in general that for any continuous function $H(x)$ over the interval $[a,b]$, there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_0^1H(x)dx=H(c)$$
Applying this to the interval $[0,1]$ and taking $H(x)=\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert$ we get
$$\int_0^1H(x)dx$$
$$=H(c) \text{ for some } c\in (0,1)$$
$$\le \sup_{t\in (0,1)}H(t)$$
$$\le \sup_{t\in [0,1]}H(t)$$

which means that for any two continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over $[0,1]$ we get
$$\rho(f,g)$$
$$=\int_0^1 \vert f(x)-g(x)\vert dx$$
$$\le \sup_{t\in [0,1]} \vert f(t)-g(t)\vert$$
$$=\rho' (f,g)$$

i.e.
$$\rho  (f,g)\le \rho  (f,g)$$

Now to prove that $\mathcal{T}_\rho$ is a subset of $\mathcal{T}_{\rho'}$
For any function $f\in C[0,1]$ and any strictly positive real number $r$, if
$$g\in B_r^{\rho'} (f)$$
$$\Rightarrow \rho'(f,g)<r$$
$$\Rightarrow \rho(f,g)<r \text{ since }\rho (f,g)\le \rho'(f,g)$$
$$\Rightarrow g\in B_r^{\rho} (f)$$

which means that for every $f\in C[0,1]$ and for every $r>0$,
$$B_r^{\rho'} (f)\subseteq B_r^{\rho} (f)$$
so every open set in $\mathcal{T}_{\rho}$ is also open in $\mathcal{T}_{\rho'}$ making
$$\mathcal{T}_{\rho}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\rho'}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking way too hard about this. Here are two things you should note:

1. The metric $\rho'$ is the metric that describes uniform convergence. What can you say about the behavior of uniform convergence with respect to the metric? In particular, if a set $C$ is closed in the topology induced by $\rho'$, then what can you say about $C$ in the topology induced by $\rho$?
2. Once again, the metric $\rho'$ describes uniform convergence. If the topologies were the same, then they would have the same convergent sequences. Can you find a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a continuous function in $\rho$ but not in $\rho'$?

Answer (score 0):

First, the two metrics $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are respectively issued from the two norms
$$\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt,\quad\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$$
hence to compare $\mathcal T_\rho$ and $\mathcal T_{\rho'},$ you just have to compare these norms.

$\mathcal T_\rho\subset\mathcal T_{\rho'}$ because
$$\|f\|_1\le\int_0^1\|f\|_\infty\,\mathrm dt=\|f\|_\infty.$$

$\mathcal T_{\rho'}\not\subset\mathcal T_\rho$ because the sequence $f_n(x):=x^n$ converges to $0$ for $\|~\|_1,$ whereas it does not converge uniformly to a *continuous* function on $[0,1]$ (its pointwise limit is discontinuous at $1$).